# How to use the @page css rule with vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a page that i would like to be printed in landscape mode like so :

```
@page {
    margin: 0;
    size: A4 landscape;
}
```

However, since all style sections of all my files get bundled together, this style affects every single page in my app.

Usually, i would assign a unique id to my component, and use that to apply the style more selectively :

```
@page {
    #my-unique-id{
        margin: 0;
        size: A4 landscape;
    }
}
```

But this is not valid, as the @page rule can't have any further selector (logical, since it should affect the whole page and cant be targeted).

How can i proceed to have this rule affect only the currently loaded page, and have all my other pages be in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

The `<style>` tag can be anywhere in you HTML document. So as a workaround you could add a `<style>` tag inside your `<template>` like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <style>
      @page {
        margin: 0;
        size: A4 landscape;
      }
    </style>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

It may not be the cleanest of solutions but it gets the job done and only applies your @page rule on this one page.